# Overwriting an Open File in Windows

Tags: file, winapi

In what situations does Windows allow you to overwrite an open file? Is that ever allowed? This includes renaming a different file to the same name as an open file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for `CreateFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx), there is this `dwShareMode` parameter.  This can determine what another process can do with that file while it's open.

Specifying `FILE_SHARE_READ` lets another process open the file for reading.  There's `FILE_SHARE_WRITE`, which means that another process can write to it.  There's also `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`, which allows delete and (IIRC) also rename.

If someone opened the file without `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` and you open the file for write access, you'll get `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`.  Otherwise you should be able to write to it.

Unfortunately if one process comes along and doesn't set sharing flags to allow something you need, you're pretty much out of luck.  Although you might be able to use [`MoveFileEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365240(VS.85).aspx) with the option `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT`.  But I'm not sure if that works; I don't know much about that call except that it exists.  :-)